# Inserting on file path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now I have files being output to a path; "C:\Users\Daniel\Average.txt"

I'm trying to write a function to input the current timestamp after the "Average" but before the .txt

I know this is pretty elementary, but I don't know where to begin...

EDIT: I originally had it hardcoded;
`string path = "C:\Users\Daniel\Average.txt";`

Comment: You should post the code that you are using to write to the file.  That way we can see how you are approaching the problem.

Comment: let's see some attempt....

Comment: string path = GetTextPath();
                if (path.Contains(".txt"))
                {
                }

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

```
var info=new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Average.txt");
var span=TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks).ToString();
var name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(info.FullName);
name=(new[] { name, span, info.Extension }).Aggregate(String.Concat);
```

The `name` is what you want finally.

There's another way to composite with a full name:

```
var info=new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Average.txt");
var span=TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks).ToString();
var fullName=info.FullName;
var length=fullName.LastIndexOf(info.Extension);
fullName=fullName.Substring(0, length);
fullName=(new[] { fullName, span, info.Extension }).Aggregate(String.Concat);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this instead:

```
var outputFile = @"C:\Users\Daniel\Average.txt";
var outputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFile);

var fileWithTimeStamp = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputFile),
                                 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"),
                                 Path.GetExtension(outputFile));
var outputWithTimeStamp = Path.Combine(outputDir, fileWithTimeStamp);
```

My Test with LINQPad:

```
outputWithTimeStamp.Dump();
```

`C:\Users\Daniel\Average_201304230828184465.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will work for you:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\Users\Daniel\Average"+DateTime.Now.ToString(ADD_FORMAT_HERE) +".txt");
```

Then you will need to dump the contents into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try string.format:

```
string Today = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM_dd");
string name = string.Format(@"Average_{0}.txt",Today);
```

You can alter the `DateTime.Now.ToString(` to include seconds, minutes etc...

Answer (score 0):

//have a string variable which holds your output

String output;

File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Daniel\Average" + DateTime.Now + ".txt",output);

this will create the text file and writes the output to that file.